# Efficient algorithm for enumerating minimal vertex separators

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

Let $G$ be a non-empty connected undirected graph, which is not a complete graph. We treat $G$ as a set, writing $G \setminus \{v\}$ for vertices $v$, etc; subsets of $G$ should be understood as induced subgraphs. A set $S \subseteq G$ is called a *separator* if $G \setminus S$ is a disconnected graph. A separator $S$ is called *minimal* if there is no $S' \subsetneq S$ such that $S'$ is a separator of $G$.

For practical(-ish) reasons I am interested in enumerating the minimal separators of graphs $G$.

> What are fast algorithms to enumerate the minimal separators of $G$?

In the 1999 paper [Generating All the Minimal Separators of a Graph](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226652711_Generating_All_the_Minimal_Separators_of_a_Graph), the authors give an algorithm that gives all the minimal separators in $\mathcal O(|V|^3|T|)$, where $T$ is the set of all minimal separators. I have found it quite fast in practical situations where $|T|$ is not too large.

Are there any better or alternative algorithms out there?

I am interested in solutions that work for general graphs.

Comment: If you find your answer, feel free to answer your own question as well.  That is highly appreciated.